# Regular expression that only matches internal Markdown links without .md extension

Tags: regex, markdown, regex-negation

I have a project with lots of Markdown files that include internal and external (start with `http`) links. Some of these internal links don't have a .md file extension and so don't work when rendered outside of Jekyll.

Examples:

```
[link text 1](internal-link)
[link text 2](internal-link-2.md)
[link text 3](http://external-link...)
```

I am looking for a regular expression that only matches the first of these three cases - internal link without `.md` file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After refining, this could be it:

```
\[[^]]+\]\((?!http:)(?!.+\.md).+\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/0uW1cl/5

(removed the capture Groups again)

Comment: Similar to what I played around with as well, unfortunately only accidentally works. Check this with more examples: http://regexr.com/3h0lq Somehow excludes everything with last character `.` - but not `http` beginning...

Comment: This here shows what is happening with your suggested regexs (I only added some capture groups): https://regex101.com/r/0uW1cl/3 It is excluding the individual characters. (But thanks for the serious answer anyway!)

Comment: you willl have to re-add your capturing groups though

Comment: Yep, that looks good. First part doesn't work in JS mode, but then `\[.*\]\((?!http:)(?!.+\.md).+\)` does: https://regex101.com/r/0uW1cl/6

Comment: Grml... in Visual Studio Code where I want to use this it only works in "search this file", not in "all files search". I hate computers sometimes.

Comment: try notepad++ , free, works with regex in searches, can do search in files or mark occurences, has a nice hitlist and some code coloring capabilities- not  sure if its regex can do negative lookaheads though

Comment: Thanks, that works. (Remove the `:` from the answer maybe, should also exclude `https`). Has minor problems with multiple links per line, but not a deal breaker.

Comment: Adding a negative lookahead for `#` also includes pure anchor links: https://regex101.com/r/0uW1cl/7 `\[.*\]\((?!http:)(?!#)(?!.+\.md).+\)`
(Minor problems with `.md` inside filenames as well, but edge case and not relevant)